# Cache HTML Pages generated by Bottle

Tags: python, caching, bottle

I need to cache some generated HTML Files to speed up the view process of my webservice. I know which information can be cached and which not, but i'm struggling with the implementation.

I thought about a decorator like this:

```
cache = {}

def cached(c):
    if c not in cache:
        cache[c] = {}
    def cached_wrapper(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            if args[0] in cache[c]:
                print("Cache hit --> %s" %cache[c][args[0]])
            else:
                cache[c][args[0]] = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return cache[c][args[0]]

        return inner
    return cached_wrapper

@route("/some/file/<id>")
@cached("some-cache")
def get_some_file(id):
    # templating goes here...
    return "[...]"
```

where for this example the storage is a dictionary but could easily extended to file-based storage or database.

But the question is: is this really a good idea? How can i implement a cache for files better or easier?

I do not want to use other services in front of the python code because the app should run standalone.

Comment: For a little more flexibility, you might look at something like [dogpile.cache](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/dogpile.cache/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using [HTTP's built-in caching mechanisms](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/caching)?

```
bottle.response.set_header('Expires', 'Fri, 14 Dec 2014 09:24:15 GMT')
```

You can also set `Last-Modified` and check the `If-Modified-Since` request header.  (There's also `E-tag`, in lieu of `Last-Modified`.)

If you insist on rolling your own, then: your high-level idea to use a wrapper (decorator) to cache seems sound; but your implementation needs work.  It has no expiry, and it doesn't cleanly consider the full set of cache keys (which should include the operation (function or route) as well as all arguments).

Comment: but this is client only and i need a server side cache.

Comment: Why?  (In any case, Last-modified and E-tag are handled by the server.)